# Website not loading completely

Tags: web-development, wordpress, godaddy, safari

I have a client on [Fiverr](http://fiverr.com) and had ordered me a job to design a website and upload it. I completed the site using wordpress and uploaded to his godaddy server. 
The problem is that, He says the website doesn't load in his PC ( and he is using Mac). The page displays only the black background. And he even tried on some of his friends' PC and got the same problem.
But the site is OK and I can access it and I tried it in different PCs. The screenshot he showed to me was from the Safari browser.
I am a windows user and haven't tried in safari. 
What could be the problem? Why isn't the site loading on the Clients PC?
The site is: [Above & Beyond Escorts](http://abovebeyondescorts.com)

The screenshot provided by the client is:
[image: Screenshot from Client]

Comment: Some of the URL's are pointing to `http://localhost/`. Maybe your client has to clear the cache and then reload the page? - Btw: you should mark your question as "NSFW" (not safe for work).

Answer (score 3):

The missing image is being called localy from your PC.  That's why you can see it, but no one else can:

Here is the code:

```
<img src="http://localhost/abi/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo1.png"
```

You need to change it to the location of the file on the server. There are also some other resources that you are still calling form you local PC, you need to update them all to the address of the files on the server.